# Fire textbox OnTextChanged event dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, textbox

I am working with AJAX and ASP.NET, I have a page with 2 textboxes and 1 label in an update panel, I want the OnTextChanged event to fire whenever the user types something in the textbox.

Right now, I got it working but it only fires the event after the user finishes typing and loses focus from the textbox, how can I get it to fire the event EVERYTIME the user types something.. Like this:

A > (fires event) > P > (fires event) > P > (fires event) > L > (fires event) > E (fires event)

Comment: Attach an event handler for the `onkeyup`?

Comment: tried adding "onKeyUp='textbox_TextChanged'" to both tbxQuantity and tbxPrice, it still doesn't fire the event dynamically when typing.

Comment: You can't do that on the tag itself. You need to write Javascript code. Also, what's gonna be fired can't be handled on the server side, unless you do a bit more work.

Comment: have u used autocomplete extender???

Comment: @MelanciaUK actually what I want to do is quite simple, just getting the value of tbxQuantity * tbxPrice, but I just can't get it working. Is it possible to do that with javascript without server's intervention?

Comment: @InnovativeDan- ajax autocompleteExtender is much more easier ... you should go for that buddy....

Comment: @Rony how do I use autocomplete to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to Register the Client Script that triggers the Event. the client script shall be javascript. and mind that you make `AJAX` call to communicate to the server Instead of POSTBACKING..

```
string scriptTest = "";

scriptText += @"function DisplayCharCount() {";
scriptText += "   spanCounter.innerText = " +
                 "document.forms[0].TextBox1.value.length";
scriptText += "}";

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CounterScript", scriptText, True);

TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "DisplayCharCount()");
```